# Translate GPIO pwm commands to linux sysfs interface

Tags: linux, pwm, sysfs

I am trying to translate some raspberry pi gpio pwm commands to use the linux sysfs interface to control the pins instead in order to get the same pwm output. The goal of this is to provide pwm output to control the brightness of an external display. The only instructions I have for the display are [here](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4inch_HDMI_LCD), which just gives the directions:

```
gpio -g pwm 18 0 
gpio -g mode 18 pwm (occupied pins are PWM pins) 
gpio pwmc 1000

Control brightness: gpio -g pwm 18 X (X takes values between 0 and 1024), 0 is the brightest, and 1024 is the darkest.
```

To get this to work with the [sysfs interface](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/pwm.html#using-pwms-with-the-sysfs-interface), I need to know values to set the pwm `period` and `duty_cycle` fields. I am new to pwm stuff, but it seems to me like the pi gpio commands leave out some information about some defaults. As I understand it, the "gpio pwmc 1000" command would set the clock divider to 1000 (units are a mystery though), but then I don't know what the "X" in `gpio -g pwm 18 X` translates to in the period/duty_cycle paradigm. Maybe my understanding is wrong but it doesn't seem like it could be the duty_cycle if it can go up to 1024 when the clock divider is only 1000 and duty cycle needs to be <= clock divider? And again the units of "X" aren't clear. Any advice on how to calculate the period and duty_cycle values to move through the full spectrum that the instructions indicate?

Some notes for clarity, I am aware that the sysfs interface is technically deprecated but it is what I have to use for this project. This will ultimately not be ran on raspberry pi, this will be being run on a [Le Potato](https://libre.computer/products/aml-s905x-cc/) device, I just need help understanding the pwm output of the raspberry pi gpio commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. `gpio pwmc 1000` seems to imply a period of 1 ms (might be wrong on the units but it didn't seem to matter for my use case), and the "X" in `gpio -g pwm 18 X` does change the duty_cycle, but it is just setting the fractional duty cycle of X / 1024. So `gpio -g pwm 18 512` would correspond to 512/1024 = 50% duty_cycle. To get the same behavior with sysfs you would set the duty_cycle as period * (X / 1024).

So if I wanted to mirror the output of the commands `gpio pwmc 1000` and `gpio -g pwm 18 512` in sysfs (which is in nanoseconds) I would set period to 1000000 and duty_cycle to 500000

Answer (score 1):

The sysfs provides no PWM support.  You will have to write your own software to switch the GPIO on/off with appropriate delays.

To find the frequency and dutycycle of those pwm commands you could use [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or this [Python script](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_read_PWM_py) to measure the output.

Comment: Updated post for clarity, I can use (and have tested) pwm functionality through sysfs as this will be running on a Le Potato device, not a raspberry pi. All I need help with is understanding the pwm output of the raspberry pi gpio pwm commands to convert it to my system. I have tried to install raspbian on the le potato but wasn't able to get gpio working, piscope is a good idea though if I am able to keep fiddling and get gpio working on raspbian

Comment: This site is for Raspberry Pi questions only.

Comment: yes, I am just trying to get an understanding of the pwm output of the raspberry pi commands